# Call model function with parameter from view in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-blade, laravel-5.5

I have two models that are in one to many relationship

`Tour.php`

```
class Tour extends Model{
protected $table = 'tours';

  public function datePrice()
  {
    return $this->hasMany('App\DatePrice', 'tour_id')->orderBy('start', 'asc');
  }    
}
```

and `DatePrice.php`

```
class DatePrice extends Model
{
 public $timestamps = false;
 protected $table = 'dateprice';
 protected $fillable = [
'tour_id',
'start_day',
'start_month',
'start_year',
'end_day',
'end_month',
'end_year',
'price'];
 public function tour() 
 {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Tour', 'tour_id');
 }

 public function scopeFixedDates($query, $date)
 {
    return $query->where('start_year', '=' , $date);
 }
}
```

I'm trying to get dates of a tour according to the year passed as parameter to the model function in my `tour.show` route and view . My code in show.blade.php view to get data is:

```
@foreach($tour->datePrice()->FixedDates(date('Y')) as $date)
<tr>
<td>
{{ date("jS M, Y", strtotime($date->start_month.'/'.$date->start_day.'/'.$date->start_year )) }}
</td>
<td>
    {{ date("jS M, Y", strtotime($date->end_month.'/'.$date->end_day.'/'.$date->end_year )) }}
</td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```

The trouble I'm having with the above code is it isn't throwing any error message or giving me the results. I've 1 row filled with start year of 2017. The table supposed to be filled with data but it is empty. When i dump and die `{{$date}}` inside foreach loop the result is blank page.I would be thankful if anyone could point out the mistake I'm making or the suggest other alternative way to my desired output.

Comment: I'm getting this error message `Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 62918656 bytes)` after using your code snipped\t.

Comment: I've made modifications to my `FixedDates()` method. `return $query->where('tour_id', '=' , $id )->where('start_year', '=' , $date)->get();`            
My table structure for `dateprice` is `id | tour_id | start_day | start_month | start_year | end_day | end_month | end_year `.And got this error.

Comment: `SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'start' in 'order clause' (SQL: select * from `dateprice` where `dateprice`.`tour_id` = 1 and `dateprice`.`tour_id` is not null and `tour_id` = 1 and `start_year` = 2017 order by `start` asc)`

Answer (score 0):

You do not access relations in this manner:

`$tour->datePrice()`

instead you use the magic property:

`$tour->date_price`

and I think it's best to use scope with different case:

`$tour->date_price->fixedDates(date('Y')`

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but your snippet is's helping much. Your code snippet is throwing `Call to a member function fixedDates() on null` error.

Comment: perhaps i'm wrong about the case style of `date_price`, and you want to use `datePrice` instead or something. The point is you access a magic _property_ instead of the relationship _method_

Answer (score 0):

```
@foreach($tour->datePrice()->FixedDates(date('Y'))->get() as $date)
```

but don't do it in the view template, prepare your data first in a controller and pass it to the view:

```
// controller
view(..)->with(['dates' => $tour->datePrice()->FixedDates(date('Y'))->get()]);

// view
@foreach($dates as $date)
```

The reason your code is *kinda working* is the fact that you pass `Eloquent\Builder` class to the foreach, and as such, it is a valid parameter for the construct, but it does not do what you want/expect obviously.

Comment: I'm getting error `SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'start' in 'order clause' (SQL: select * from `dateprice` where `dateprice`.`tour_id` = 1 and `dateprice`.`tour_id` is not null and `tour_id` = 1 and `start_year` = 2017 order by `start` asc)`

Comment: @TanjaForsberg well, the error says you don't have such a column, right? I guess from your snippet, that you'd rather use `start_year`/`start_month`/`start_day`, which btw is not the best approach for storing dates in SQL ;)

Comment: Found solution I removed `->orderBy('start', 'asc')` from dateprice method in Tour.php